# Entity Framework Core - Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'EntryType' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: .net-core, razor, foreign-keys

I am trying to create my first Razor Pages using .Net Core and have come across a problem. I have the following 2 models:

[image]

and:

[image]

As you can see, an Entry can have an Entry type... Pretty straight forward. The issue I have is when trying to create a new Entry record:

[image]

I am populating a **SelectList** as follows:

[image]

[image]

which is being consumed for display:

[image]

However when I attempt to create a new **Entry** I get the following error:

[image]

It seems as if it is not only trying to create an Entry record in the database, but also the **EntryType** that is against the new Entry, instead of just populating the foreign key value (**EntityTypeId**) in the database:

[image]

I am hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a foreign key `EntryTypeId` to the `Entry` model

```
public int EntryTypeId {get;set;}
```

Then bind the select in the view like this

```
asp-for="Entry.EntryTypeId"
```

This way, all the information for that `EntryType` are copied or mapped to the `Entry` entity you're creating using the EntryTypeId specified. You are trying to modify existing entry Id the way you currently do it.

Comment: Thanks for that... I will give that a go! I have found another way to get it to work (posted below) however yours feels more like the standard practice. Thanks! Will test and update.

Comment: Just adding the EntryTypeId property into the Entry model is still giving me the same results. Do I need to re-build the scaffolding or push the database changes before it will work do you think?

Comment: @CJH yes, you need to add-migration and update-database. Also, do not forget to make the changes in the view `asp-for="Entry.EntryTypeId"` and not `asp-for="Entry.EntryType.ID"`

Comment: lol - I had realised I missed off one of the view changes - but all working now! :D I hadnt made the add-migration or update yet as the DB looks like it is already equiped for that field but will run it off now for good measure! Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that adding the below two lines (braced in red) makes it work:

[image]

However **Qudos** answer above seems more 'Correct' so will give that a go! Thanks!